# Testing XMLHttpRequest onload() callback functionality in Jest

Tags: javascript, html, jestjs, mocking, xmlhttprequest

I'm testing some plain HTML and vanilla javascript with Jest and would like to be able to mock the XMLHttpRequest with the exception of the `onload()` callback function I've defined.

I found a few examples of how to mock out the entire XMLHttpRequest, but I'd like to be able to mock everything EXCEPT the onload function I've defined in my code (thats the logic I'm trying to test).

my javascript function I'd like to test looks like:

```
function foo() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/expected/url', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.send();
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            var array = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            array.forEach(function (object) {
                // do some stuff
            });

            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
        }
    };
};

module.exports = {
    foo
}
```

and my test file looks like:

```
var script = require('../fs/script.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../fs/index.html'), 'utf8');

const createMockXHR = responseJSON => {
    const mockXHR = {
        open: jest.fn(),
        send: jest.fn(),
        setRequestHeader: jest.fn(),
        status: 200,
        readyState: 4,
    };
    return mockXHR;
};

describe('Foo', function () {
    const oldXMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
    let mockXHR = null;

    beforeEach(() => {
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.toString();
        mockXHR = createMockXHR();
        window.XMLHttpRequest = jest.fn(() => mockXHR);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        window.XMLHttpRequest = oldXMLHttpRequest;
        jest.resetModules();
    });

    it('is set, section is collapsed', function () {
        mockXHR.response = '{ "data": "point"}';

        var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
        var elementToCollapse = bar.nextElementSibling;

        script.foo();

        expect(mockXHR.send).toBeCalled();
        expect(mockXHR.onload).toBeCalled();
        // expect some more things
    });
});
```

I know the above is wrong because `onload()` is not defined anywhere in my mock, but the only crumb I've found as to how I might be able to do that throws an error:

```
const createMockXHR = responseJSON => {
    const mockXHR = {
        open: jest.fn(),
        send: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
            onload = this.onload.bind(this);
            onerror = this.onerror.bind(this);
        }),
        setRequestHeader: jest.fn(),
        status: 200,
        readyState: 4,
    };
    return mockXHR;
};
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')

      12 |         send: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
    > 13 |             onload = this.onload.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

While not technically answering the question, I have solved my problem of not being able to test the `onload()` inline function by putting the logic in a separate function and testing that:

```
function foo_logic(request) {
    // the logic
}

function foo() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/expected/url', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.send();
    request.onload = function () { foo_logic(request) };
};

module.exports = {
    foo_logic,
    foo
}
```

Then testing:

```
var script = require('../fs/script.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../fs/index.html'), 'utf8');

const createMockXHR = responseJSON => {
    const mockXHR = {
        open: jest.fn(),
        send: jest.fn(),
        setRequestHeader: jest.fn(),
        status: 200,
        readyState: 4,
    };
    return mockXHR;
};

describe('Foo', function () {
    const oldXMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
    let mockXHR = null;

    beforeEach(() => {
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.toString();
        mockXHR = createMockXHR();
        window.XMLHttpRequest = jest.fn(() => mockXHR);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        window.XMLHttpRequest = oldXMLHttpRequest;
        jest.resetModules();
    });

    it('is set, section is collapsed', function () {
         mockXHR.responseText = JSON.stringify({
            data: "point"
        });

        var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
        var elementToCollapse = bar.nextElementSibling;

        script.foo_logic(mockXHR);

        // expect some things about bar and elementToCollapse
    });
});
```